# Adding Complex Keys in the Dictionary! Does it effect the performance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am just writing a program that requires Dictionary as (in C#.net-4.5)

```
 Dictionary<List<Button>, String> Label_Group = new Dictionary<List<Button>, String>();
```

my friend suggests to use key as string, does this makes any difference in performance while doing the search!,

I am just curious how it work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, the lookup based on a `List<Button>` will be faster than based on a `string`, because `List<T>` doesn't override `Equals`. Your keys will just be compared by reference effectively - which is blazingly cheap.

Compare that with using a string as a key:

- The hash code needs to be computed, which is non-trivial
- Each string comparison performs an *equality* check, which has a short cut for equal references (and probably different lengths), but will otherwise need to compare each character until it finds a difference or reaches the end

(Taking the hash code of an object of a type which doesn't override `GetHashCode` *may* require allocation of a SyncBlock - I think it used to. That may be more expensive than hashing very short strings...)

It's rarely a good idea to use a collection as a dictionary key though - and if you need anything other than reference equality for key comparisons, you'll need to write your own `IEqualityComparer<>`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `List<T>` does not override `GetHashCode`, so its use as a key would have similar performance to using an `object`.